# Select data from pandas dataframe based on a column, consisting of values in a list?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which looks like the following:

[image]

I need to select those row in which any of the three angles are not close to 90 or 180 by a value of 35. For example, I need to select rows which have Angle values like: 50, 50, 140.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

```
def check_angle(df_list):
    ANGLE_THRESHOLD = 35
    ANGLE_NINETY = 90
    ANGLE_ONE_EIGHTY = 180
    for df in df_list:
        print df.loc[df['Angle'].str.split(',')[0] >= (ANGLE_NINETY + ANGLE_THRESHOLD)]
```

Till now, I have tried this, but its throwing KeyError.

Comment: You should show what you tried, at least a snippet of your code. Please edit the question.

Answer (score 0):

If `df` is your data frame

```
   A                  B
0  1  92.36,89.1,177.47
1  2  90.49,90.9,178.97
2  3  91.66,92.4,177.08
3  4    94,86.87,174.92
4  5  97.41,85.65,173.8
5  5   20.41,20.65,20.8
```

you can split it with split(',') and iterate through the rows.

```
df_tmp = pd.DataFrame([[val.split(",")[0],val.split(",")[1],val.split(",")[2] ]  for val in df.B])
```

The returned boolean can be used to create a new dataframe

```
df_tmp2 = pd.DataFrame({
"val1in":(df_tmp[0].astype(float)>(90.-35.)) & (df_tmp[0].astype(float)<(90.+35.)) | (df_tmp[0].astype(float)>(180.-35.)) & (df_tmp[0].astype(float)<(180.+35.)),
"val2in":(df_tmp[1].astype(float)>(90.-35.)) & (df_tmp[1].astype(float)<(90.+35.)) | (df_tmp[1].astype(float)>(180.-35.)) & (df_tmp[1].astype(float)<(180.+35.)),
"val3in":(df_tmp[2].astype(float)>(90.-35.)) & (df_tmp[2].astype(float)<(90.+35.)) | (df_tmp[2].astype(float)>(180.-35.)) & (df_tmp[2].astype(float)<(180.+35.))
})
```

based on which you can select the rows

```
print (df[np.all(df_tmp2,axis =1)==False])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({"A":[1,2,3,4],"val":[[140,89.1,177.47],[90.49,90.9,178.90],[91.66,92.4,177.08],[135,85.65,173.8]]})

B=[]
C=[]
D=[]

for i in range(len(df)):
    B.append(df["val"][i][0])
    C.append(df["val"][i][1])
    D.append(df["val"][i][2])





df["B"]=B
df["C"]=C
df["D"]=D

print(df.query("(B < 180-35 & B > 90+35) | (C < 180-35 & C > 90+35) | (D < 180-35 & D > 90+35)"))


   A                  val      B      C       D
0  1  [140, 89.1, 177.47]  140.0  89.10  177.47
3  4  [135, 85.65, 173.8]  135.0  85.65  173.80
```

For convenience you can also drop the colmns B,C,D after selection

Comment: Naturally this presumes that the 3 angles are not in a single string but in a list like [Ang1, Ang2, Ang3] object. Otherwise you have to use the split() function as described in the other two answers

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with `expand=True` for DataFrame and cast to `float`s, then compare with conditions and last use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with inverted mask by `~` and [`all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) for check all `False`s rows:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({"S/N":[1,2,3,4],
                 "Angle":['50,50,140','90.49,90.9,178.90',
                          '91.66,92.4,177.08','135,85.65,173.8']})
print (df)
               Angle  S/N
0          50,50,140    1
1  90.49,90.9,178.90    2
2  91.66,92.4,177.08    3
3    135,85.65,173.8    4


AT = 35
AN = 90
AO = 180

a = df['Angle'].str.split(',', expand=True).astype(float)
m = ((a > AN-AT) & (a < AN+AT)) | ((a > AO-AT) & (a < AO+AT))
print (m)
       0      1      2
0  False  False  False
1   True   True   True
2   True   True   True
3  False   True   True

df = df[(~m).all(axis=1)]
print (df)
       Angle  S/N
0  50,50,140    1
```